# ALTER/ADD COLUMN as SUM of two or more existing columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know how to do it in creating a table but is there a way to add or update a column and set it as the sum of two or more existing columns? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a computed column:

```
alter table t add column sumcol as (col1 + col2);
```

The value is calculated when the table is queried, so it is always up-to-date.